# Local.xml, can it be used for .phtml also?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, local.xml

Just a general question regarding using a `local.xml` file in Magento.

I'm now using it to hold my layout modifications, however I read somewhere that it can also be used to hold modifications to your template (phtml) files. Is that true? If so, how would you do it? Can't seem to find any info on this in the Magento (CE) Documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by that? And also `"I read somewhere"` ... sources?

Comment: I mean all changes that one needs to make to a Magento site that are NOT CSS. Can they be  captured in the local.xml file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't bookmark the site where I read about this...

Comment: An XML file has specific content which is structured xml markup used to create a node tree for Magento's configuration to show where output blocks will be placed, or parameters/data will be included. Template files (phtml) are a mixture of PHP and HTML that creates html blocks for presentation, not something you would stick in an XML file.

Comment: OK thanks ! All clear now! Thanks for your help! I'm still learning ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, to not misread `local.xml` and `local.xml`. There are two:

- `app/etc/local.xml` is part of the config, holds the database credentials and everything else you want in your config.
- `app/design/<frontend>/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml` which is a layout file and loaded last

So with the second you can manipulate finally your theme.

Comment: I mean the one in app/design/.... Can that only hold changes to your layout or also changes to your template files?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please edit the question, give an example, maybe add a screenshot and then write a comment ,because I'm not pinged when you edit :)

Comment: The question was answered by 7ochem. Thanks for your help anyway!